# set focus after append new row in table not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have write this code

```
function addNew(){
$('#container').append(
'<tr class="records" height="1em">'
+'<td align="center"><input  id="" name="UraiF" ></td></tr>');
$('table#myTable tr:last td:first input').focus();}
```

the HTML code

```
<table id="#myTable">
<thead>
<th style="width:5%;" align="center">No.</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="container">
<tr class="records">
<td><input  id="" name="UraiF" ></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

this the button on even click :

```
<button onclick="addNew()"></button>
```

but nothing happened,can anyone help me

Comment: You are appending the content to `#container` and you are finding for input in element with id #myTable.

Comment: what is `#container` and `#myTable `

Comment: you are appending row to the `container`, is this a table id? please share your html code too

Comment: so may be `$('#container tr:last td:first input').focus();`

Comment: you forgot to  close the input element , and give it a type - on top of whatever else you're doing wrong with appending that we can't tell without lookng at the HTML , please post

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console ?? and are you sure you are calling addNew();  ?? or just defining it?

Comment: I have added the html, please check back sir

Comment: @ScottSelby, it is ok if input tag is not closed, browser won't give any error. For more information see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: @user3502930 Does this helps... http://jsfiddle.net/8oL94s95/1/

Comment: isn't that new to HTML5 ?  either way - you're probably right , that wasn't it

Comment: do you know how to check for errors?  because you are getting one I am pretty sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to find input inside `container` which is tbody, also make sure that id of this tbody must be unique throughout the DOM. please see below code

```
function addNew(){
  $('#container').append(
  '<tr class="records" height="1em">'
   +'<td align="center"><input  id="" name="UraiF" ></td></tr>');
  $('tbody#container tr:last td:first input').focus();
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this did not work for me. But this did: $('#container').closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').focus();

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything on here, I finally figured out why FOCUS wasn't working after an APPEND/AFTER/BEFORE.  The FOCUS wasn't finding the #id because the DOM wasn't changed/populated with the new code.  I had to "delay" the FOCUS in order for it to work.  Here is the code I used.

`setTimeout(function() { $("#id_of_element").focus() }, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

first of all check to see if there are any console errors - they are usually prety descriptive of what is going on and you can fix them,

secondly - this may be getting added and you just don't know it because you have an invalid input tag as the only thing in your row.  try fixing it

```
function addNew(){
   $('#container').append(
   '<tr class="records" height="1em">'
   +'<td align="center"><input  id="" name="UraiF" type="text" /></td></tr>');
   $('table#myTable tr:last td:first input').focus();
}
```

also - to simplify things  ,  I would of just wrote :

```
$('#container input').last();
```

and another thing , this is bad  and confusing :

`<table id="#myTable">`   // -- take that # out of here

Comment: am sure the rows has added in my table and i can see that... but the question here's "how to set focus in that new addded input"

add elm "type=text" does not change anything